# Mongoose schema/methods disappearing when overwriting subdocument

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a schema with a method - 2 variations.  They both work fine when adding an address the firs time but version one will blow up when adding another address (i.e. when it goes through the for loop). What I mean by blowing up is that it seems to destroy my order instance - there is no more 'save' method.

The schema

```
var Address = new Schema({
  type: { type: String, enum: ['shipping', 'billing'] },
  street: { type: String, required: true },
  city: { type: String, required: true },
  region: String,
  country: String,
  postal: { type: String, required: true },
});

var Order = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  address: [Address]
});
```

Now if I have added an addAddress() method to my schema. Here are the 2 versions I have tried.

```
// Version 1 - has issues on subsequent call
Order.methods.addAddress = function() {

  var data = { type: 'shipping', city: 'Tempe', postal: '85281', street: '420 Mill Ave'};

  for(var i = this.address.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
    if(this.address[i].type === type) {
     delete address[i];   
    }
  }
  this.address.push(data);
}

// Version 2 - works fine
Order.methods.addAddress = function() {

  var data = { type: 'shipping', city: 'Tempe', postal: '85281', street: '420 Mill Ave'};

  var found = false;
  for(var i = this.address.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
    if(this.address[i].type === type) {
      found = true;
      this.address[i] = data;
    }
  }
  if(!found)
    this.address.push(data);
}
```

Trying to save after using V1 that will yield this error:

```
Uncaught Exception
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save'
    at /var/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1270:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at model.pre.err.stack (/var/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1252:12)
    at model._next (/var/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks/hooks.js:50:30)
    at model.proto.(anonymous function) [as save] (/var/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks/hooks.js:96:20)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/var/controllers/cart.js:79:11)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/var/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:171:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (/var/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:88:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/var/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:101:20)
```

Let's take the following code:

```
Order.findById(id.exec(function(err, o) {
  o.addAddress('shipping', { street: '1000 Mill Ave', city: 'Tempe', postal: '85281' });
  console.log(o);
  o.save(function(err, order) {
  });
})
```

Notice the console call? On each variation it appear that the order object is ok:

```
{
  _id: 007d0000b10000000000000c,
  address: [{
    street: '420 Mill Ave',
    postal: '85281',
    city: 'Tempe',
    type: 'shipping'
    _id: 52b2459f1547a5e12300000b
  }]
}
```

But it seems to have lost something such as the 'save' method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining the address as a dict and not as an address object. Instead you should do something like this:

```
Order.methods.addAddress = function(type, data, next) {

    // Have your removal code here

    var self = this
    var address = new Address(data)
    address.save(function(err, address) {
        if (err) {
            ...
        } else {
            self.address.push(address)
            next()
        }
    })
}
```

Notice that I'm populating the address array with an address object as per the schema definition.

Comment: The thing is that it works fine as is with a dict. Tt's the removal of it that breaks something internal. Part of the issue maybe that I am using delete instead of slice and leaving.. what do you call that.. empty decaying husks of objects so Mongoose may be freaking out when addresses is length 2 but there is nothing at index 0

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right in that assumption. It's always a problem when deleting stuff from an array within a loop. Try to remove the objects in the array with this.address[i].delete() instead, use foreach and or add the addresses that you want to save to a new array that you can override to old data with, this.address = newArray, trying to eliminate the array indexing issue.

Comment: Oh duh.. I didn't even think that my subdocs would have a delete()!

Comment: Sort of - it's remove() not delete(). So yes using remove as well as splice works - delete address[i] make a mess. The issue is entirely related to messing with the index. Didn't think it would blow up Mongoose like that though!

Comment: @Yashua would you mind marking this as the correct solution if it helped?

Comment: the issue was that you can't delete from array as it messes internal addresses. But your answer along with comments should assist someone.